# Trying to delete "left_chat_member" messages with a Telegram Bot

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying perform the following actions with a Telegram Bot:

When a `user.first_name` matches a regex:

1. Delete "join" message.
2. Kick user from the chat.
3. Delete "left" message.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the `message.id` for the "left" message since:

1. [KickChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#kickchatmember) method does not return a message object, only `true` or `false`.
2. The sent message which contains `left_chat_member` has `user.from` set to the member who kicks (In this case, the bot itself).
3. A bot can't receive updates for his own message, so the previous message is not received.

So the question is:

> Is possible to obtain the `message.id` for the message containing `left_chat_member` when is sent by the bot itself? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Maybe I could try to infer the `message.id` but I don't know if this would be possible or recommended.

Comment: Not even setting "setprivacy" in "Enable" comes that message (I'm in the same)

Comment: It may be a bug, the doc say "All bots, regardless of settings, will receive: All service messages." https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get (but it does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approximation, that emerged from a conversation with @eyaadh at https://t.me/BotTalk is:

1. When a `new_chat_members` happens, you have an `message_id` (let's say `A`)
2. Execute `kick_chat_member` (missing `message_id`)
3. And sent a message (arbitrary), you have an `message_id` (let's say `B`)

(step one is optional)

The message produced by `kick_chat_member` is `B-1`, with little probability that another message has entered right in the middle, that if the step 2 and 3 must go together in the code to reduce as much as possible the time between them.

And the `A` message serves to know the smallest id. In other words, the id in question is between `A` and `B` (guaranteed). If `A + 2` is equal to `B` the message is `B-1` (or `A+1`) guaranteed. Otherwise, there would be no certainty.

In my opinion `left_chat_member` should send the message to the bot that generates the output, with that the problem would be solved, or the execution of `kick_chat_member` should return that info.

---

### A solution

When a `new_chat_members` is launched in the function that manages it, can do the following (three IDs will be used, `id1`, `id2` and `id3`):

- `id1` is the identifier of the join message (the one that comes with `new_chat_members`).
- Then `kick_chat_member` is executed (this generates the message that the ID is not known, `id2`).
- (If the user was deleted) Any message is sent with `sendMessage` that will give us the `id3`.

Then we loop from `id3 - 1` to `id1 + 1` (including both): for each id in this loop we send a "message in response" with `sendMessage` (using in the `reply_to_message_id` parameter the id of the loop) and we check if the message that is generated contains in its parameter `reply_to_message.left_chat_member` the id of the user that we are deleting, if it is affirmative it is the message that we want to eliminate (eliminate, it is `id2`), at the end of the cycle we eliminate the "message in response" as well (the id for each step loop).

When the for cycle ends, we eliminate the messages with `id1` and `id3`.

In this way the input and output (kicked) message is eliminated with total certainty, regardless of whether other messages appear between.

I tested it by putting a wait of 3 seconds between each action in the bot and writing in the group (while the bot went step by step).

---

### Example in Python

https://github.com/schcriher/welcome-tg-bot/commit/0e4dbaa9cbff5272d682899b1433ff2b3c750a74

---

**In summary**: all the messages are answered (reply), from `id3 - 1` to `id1 + 1`, and it is searched which contains the `left_chat_member` with the user id that has been kicked.

---

**UPDATE**

Now the bot gets the service message when kicked a member. It is enough to analyze if the exit message is issued by the bot, if so it is a kick to a member of the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes in NodeJs

```
let TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
let bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
let regex = 'givenUser';  /* Part of the user first name that you wanna kick him out*/

    bot.on('new_chat_members', (data) => newMembers(data));
    bot.on('left_chat_member', (data) => leftMember(data));

    function newMembers(data) {
        let chatId = data.chat.id;
        let msgId = data.message_id;
        let userId = data.new_chat_member.id; 
        let firstName = data.new_chat_member.first_name;
        if (firstName.includes(regex)) {
            bot.deleteMessage(chatId, msgId).catch(e => console.log(e));
            bot.kickChatMember(chatId, userId).catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
}

function leftMember(data) {
    let chatId = data.chat.id;
    let msgId = data.message_id;
    let firstName = data.left_chat_member.first_name;
    if (firstName.includes(regex)) {
        bot.deleteMessage(chatId, msgId).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
}
```